# Двадцать один с половиной метров(а)?

Tags: согласование

Как правильно? Двадцать один с половиной метр? метра? метров? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Так как же правильно?

Comment: Это технический текст, метр с половиной странно как-то смотрится. Можно двадцать один и пять десятых, но интересно, как правильно с половиной.

Answer (score 4):

Двадцать один с половиной метр. Слово "метр" относится к числительному "двадцать один".

Comment: Думаю, что все-таки "метр".  Можно попробовать заменить это слово: "двадцать один с половиной миллион, двадцать один с половиной литр, двадцать один с половиной сантиметр".

Answer (score 3):

Лучше сказать "двадцать один  метр с половиной" А вообще:
 http://rudocs.exdat.com/docs/index-155824.html?page=6
Имя существительное при дробных числительных ставится всегда в форме 
родительного падежа единственного числа:
0,5 – ноль целых пять десятых грамма,
5,5 – пять с половиной метра (пять целых пять десятых метра)
21,5 - Двадцать один метр с половиной; двадцать один и пять десятых метра; "двадцать один  с половиной метр" звучит как-то просторечно, метра - ещё хуже.

Comment: >>Имя существительное при дробных числительных ставится всегда в форме родительного падежа единственного числа  
  
А как же "Восемь с половиной недель"? Переводчики оплошали?

Comment: Видимо,  всё-таки это не форма дробного числительного - восемь чего? недель с чем? с половиной.Половина-существительное. Поэтому и 21 метр с чем? - с половиной. Только звучит "двадцать один с половиной метр ткани" как-то разговорно. Всё-таки более литературно "двадцать один метр ткани с половиной".

Comment: Я вполне могу согласиться, что "двадцать один с половиной метр" звучит несколько странно. Но вопрос был не о том, а о формулировке.  
Не могу согласиться, что "...метр с половиной" - панацея, не технический это оборот, но это тоже не стоит того, чтобы копья ломать.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то Надюшка права. 
Здесь нет **дробной** части, есть некое образование со словом "половина", дробью не являющееся:

> > Вопрос № 237826 
> > Добрый день.
> > Работаю в газете. Еще на стадии подписания полосы в печать следующая фраза вызвала между мной и корректором спор: «Монтаж последнего пролета моста продолжался восемь с половиной месяца».
> > Как правильно писать — месяцА или месяцЕВ?
> > Корректор оставила первый вариант, он так и вышел.
> > А мне хочется написать второй вариант. Что думаете вы?
> > И тогда помогите разобраться во всем круге проблем с дробными числами в тексте, вот как здесь: «8,3 метра», «9 с четвертью часа» - как правильно это писать?
> > Спасибо.
> > AndAnAs
> > Ответ справочной службы русского языка
> > Существительным управляет дробная часть: 8,3 метра, 8,5 месяца (читаем: восемь и пять десятых месяца), но восемь с половиной месяцев.

Справка сама слегка запуталась в формулировках, но вариант "с половиной месяцев" дала верный. Но вместе с тем возникают определенные сложности с выбором формы для числительных, оканчивающихся на "один".

Боюсь, что в данном случае вариант "двадцать один с половиной метра" будет возможен как некий паллиатив между несвободностью выбора формы и грамматикой.

В Интернете, кстати, встречаются оба варианта, даже три, но последний (типа  "с половиной метров") всё же очень редок.

А вопрос хороший.

=======

Насчет технического текста. Если есть возможность написать "пять десятых", то, возможно, стоит воспользоваться. Но даже в техническом тексте это не всегда стоит делать. Если это какая-то неточная величина, например, "пять десятых" будет звучать слишком претенциозно.

Answer (score 1):

Для технического текста, по-моему, лучше вообще без "половинок" обойтись. *Двадцать один (целый) и пять (десятых) метра.* Без слов в скобках, более разговорный вариант (ср. *температура больного - тридцать семь и пять*, но не тридцать семь с половиной).

Возвращаясь непосредственно к вопросу. Как правильно отметила [[@Надюшка](/users/308/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0)](/users/308/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0), "метр" относится к "двадцать один" и соответственно склоняется также как и при отсутствии "с половиной" (ср. "два с половиной метр**а**", но "пять с половиной метр**ов**"). Получается, что правильно - *двадцать один с половиной метр*.

Answer (score 0):

А для меня как не русскоязычного, но хорошо чувствующего язык приемлем вариант (ответ) бегемотуса, т. е. "с половиной метра". Когда я слышу или читаю "пять с половиной миллиона", то возникает ассоциация - пять миллиона плюс еще половина миллиона, т. е. пятьсот тысяч - это эквивалент 5 500 000.

Может, это неграмотно, но, по-моему, очень даже понятно для иноязычного.

Comment: «Приемлем вариант (ответ) бегемотуса, т.е. с половиной метра»? Читайте внимательнее, ведь он  пишет: «Справка ... вариант "с половиной месяцев" дала верный». Не понятливо! Видимо, потому что не даёте свой ответ, а комментируете другой.

Comment: @Dr.Aygun  Это не совсем "мой" вариант. Это от безвыходности. Боюсь, что чувство языка Вас обмануло. Нормативным, судя по всему, следует считать ***"двадцать один с половиной метр"***,  если ориентироваться на общее правило согласования с числительным. Но это очень трудно воспринять на слух. Поэтому Вы, и не только Вы, полагаете, что согласовывать надо с "половиной", что никакими грамматиками не подтверждается, но очень хочется. А самый лучший (хотя и не совсем "честный", т.к. требует изменения порядка слов) ответ дала Людмила.